# How to base on condition to update cell value?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Everyone, I'm absolute beginner of Python and currently leaning by myself.
I have meet a problem, I hope I find talented person to teach me how to fix the issue.

1. I have two different excel to compare...

   ```
                                  Data1.xlsx                                       Data2.xlsx
    |  Name   |   City    |  Reg Date  | Gender | Check In | Check In Date |  |   Name  |  Reg Date  |
    |Alex     | Hong Kong | 2021-06-30 | Male   |    Y     |  2021-06-30   |  |Annie    | 2021-07-01 |    
    |Annie    | Hong Kong | 2021-07-01 | Female |          |               |  |Billy    | 2021-07-02 |    
    |Bob      | Taipei    | 2021-06-28 | Male   |    Y     |  2021-06-28   |  |Cathrine | 2021-07-03 |    
    |Lucy     | Tokyo     | 2021-06-28 | Female |    Y     |  2021-06-28   |  |David    | 2021-07-04 |    
    |David    | London    | 2021-07-04 | Male   |          |               |  |Eric     | 2021-07-04 |    
    |Kate     | New York  | 2021-07-03 | Female |          |               |
    |Cathrine | London    | 2021-07-03 | Female |          |               |
    |Rose     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-04 | Female |          |               |
   ```
2. Use `Name` & `Reg Date` for key to merge

   ```
   import openpyxl as xl
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   dt1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
   dt2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')
   df_merge = pd.merge(dt1, dt2[['Name', 'Reg Date']], on=['Name', 'Reg Date'], how='left', indicator=True)

      Name         City     Reg Date   Gender  Check In  Check In Date    _merge  
   0  Alex      Hong Kong  2021-06-30  Male       Y       2021-06-30    left_only     
   1  Annie     Hong Kong  2021-07-01  Female    NaN          NaN            both 
   2  Bob       Taipei     2021-06-28  Male       Y       2021-06-28    left_only    
   3  Lucy      Tokyo      2021-06-28  Female     Y       2021-06-28    left_only
   4  David     London     2021-07-04  Male      NaN          NaN            both 
   5  Kate      New York   2021-07-03  Female    NaN          NaN       left_only
   6  Cathrine  London     2021-07-03  Female    NaN          NaN            both
   7  Rose      Hong Kong  2021-07-04  Female    NaN          NaN       left_only
   ```
3. How to check equal `both` to fill `Check In` is `Y` & copy `Reg Date` to `Check In Date` ?

   ```
   for a in df_merge.iloc[:, [7]].values:
       if a == 'both':
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing and `fillna`:

```
cols = ['Check In', 'Check In Date']
mask = df_merged['_merge'].eq('both')

df_merged.loc[mask, cols] = \
    df_merged.loc[mask, cols].fillna({'Check In': 'Y',
                                      'Check In Date': df_merged['Reg Date']})
```

Output:

```
>>> df_merged
       Name       City    Reg Date  Gender Check In Check In Date     _merge
0      Alex  Hong Kong  2021-06-30    Male        Y    2021-06-30  left_only
1     Annie  Hong Kong  2021-07-01  Female        Y    2021-07-01       both
2       Bob     Taipei  2021-06-28    Male        Y    2021-06-28  left_only
3      Lucy      Tokyo  2021-06-28  Female        Y    2021-06-28  left_only
4     David     London  2021-07-04    Male        Y    2021-07-04       both
5      Kate   New York  2021-07-03  Female      NaN           NaN  left_only
6  Cathrine     London  2021-07-03  Female        Y    2021-07-03       both
7      Rose  Hong Kong  2021-07-04  Female      NaN           NaN  left_only
```